Mixed effects models with only categorical data?
This is my first time trying to run any type of mixed effects models. I have a dataset where I was instructed to use some form of mixed effect modeling (lme4 package) to see if functional traits of my species (the response variables) are spread in a way due to environment (urbanization level).
This means my response variable would be the functional traits (but I have about 4 of them, categorical data), my fixed effect would be the urbanization level (factor of levels low, medium, and high), and then my random effect I think would just be the species.
I tried to use the following but it is not working and I'm pretty sure it's because my data is categorical. So does this mean using something like glmer will just not work?
My data has the following categories and I was trying my formulas out like the following:
 # subset of my data

Genus          Sex   UrbanIntensity Sociality Nesting Diet      BodySize
  <chr>        <chr> <fct>          <fct>     <fct>   <fct>      <fct>      
1 Ceratina      M     Medium        Subsocial Cavity  Generalist Small      
2 Xenoglossa    F     Low           Solitary  Ground  Specialist Large      
3 Bombus        F     High          Social    Ground  Generalist Large      
4 Agapostemon   F     Low           Solitary  Ground  Generalist Small      
5 Ceratina      M     Low           Subsocial Cavity  Generalist Small      
6 Xenoglossa    F     Low           Solitary  Ground  Specialist Large 

# are the functional traits influenced by urban intensity level?
model <- glmer((BodySize,Sociality,Nesting,Diet) ~ UrbanIntensity + (1|Genus), data=data)

But my model is obviously wrong because I also don't think I can have multiple response variables in one go. I do have abundance as well for each genus which I think can be used as a response variable instead, but is there no way to run glmm's for something with multiple response variables (categorical or not? I could try converting these variables into numeric factor values).

It's well established that categorizing continuous or quantitative data squanders information. The resulting models are much less insightful and useful.
Imo, only some of these variables are truly categorical, e.g., Genus, Sex, Nesting. The others -- e.g,. UrbanIntensity, BodySize -- appear to have an underlying quantitative basis. If it's possible, why not revert to using this numerical information? This would simplify and, at the same time, generate better results.
Your interest is in the overall mixed effects of these variables on one another. Given this, it's possible to rethink the traditional supervised model (a target predicted by a set of independent factors) and treat the information as a large cross-classified contingency table model. Once a model is generated, it is possible to produce effect sizes or importance estimates from the results.
Fienberg's book The Analysis of Cross-Classified Categorical Data is one source for modeling wholly categorical information. It contains specific discussion and examples using speciation data such as yours.
https://www.google.co.th/books/edition/The_Analysis_of_Cross_Classified_Categor/N_QjE6NDAHUC?hl=en&gbpv=0
A related approach to Fienberg's is latent class analysis. LCA is well described in the presentation linked below. Here's the intuition. Using categorical data as input, LCA generates a model with an error term. This error is partitioned minimizing the heterogeneity in the cross-classified factors based on max likelihood metrics similar to what a classic, noncategorical clustering method would do.
https://pop.princeton.edu/sites/g/files/toruqf496/files/documents/2020Jan_LatentClassAnalysis.pdf
While this presentation relies on polCA, there is a better tool -- Latent Gold...but it requires an inexpensive license. If purchase isn't possible, their website still has a ton of white papers describing the many variants of LCA. It is well worth a look.
https://www.statisticalinnovations.com/latent-gold-6-0/

(+1) I actually didn't realize until now but looking at the variables more closely your sentiments about the categorical variables make a lot of sense. OP may consider using the original scale of the variables in order to get better insights about the data.

@ShawnHemelstrand The caveat is always that the guys extracting the information and subsequently categorizing it aren't always the same people doing the analysis and modeling. In some cases it simply isn't possible to go back to them and obtain the original numeric information.

You can't model a GLMM this way. Even if the code for this worked (which it doesn't), you are anyway mixing apples and oranges in terms of measurement. This would greatly distort whatever results you get from the model. If the categories were some kind of ordered response, then you could make the case for a multinomial logistic ordinal GLMM, but that doesn't appear to be the case here either. A latent response made up of the dependent variables could also work, but that would require switching to something like a structural equation model  (SEM) with hierarchical structures (using something like a piecewise SEM, see example here).
If that isn't an option, there is nothing inherently wrong with using four separate models so long as they are justified theoretically. Some may advise adjusting alpha accordingly, but I'm not one of those people for reasons I have outlined here before.

I see. So say I isolate each trait and make it a response. Can it still work if the response is categorical or do I need to convert everything into some form of factor numeric values? Let's say BodySize which has three possibilities I would just change it to 1,2,3 instead of small, medium, large?

Yes. For two levels of a categorical response, you would just just a logistic GLMM. For more than 2 (like body size), since it has a natural order to it, then you can use an ordinal GLMM. I came back to this answer and realize I misspoke and edited my answer, as you wouldn't use multinomial here (which is used when there is no natural order to the response). For ordinal GLMMs, you can consider the GLMMadaptive package.

The 'ordinal' package is also very good for ordinal GLMMs.
